# Query without duplicates in a specific column, leaving the most recent

Tags: sql, teradata

My table looks something like this:

```
 status_id  |  user_id    |    updated_on
 -----------+-------------+---------------------
 0001       |   0004      | 2018-02-03 14:43:48
 0002       |   0004      | 2018-02-03 10:07:33
 0003       |   0005      | 2018-02-02 09:38:21
 0003       |   0005      | 2018-02-02 09:38:21
```

And I'm running a simple query to fetch all the rows for a list of user_ids:

```
SELECT * FROM user.status
WHERE user_id IN ('0004','0005');
```

I'm looking for a way to get the same results, but without any duplicate `user_id` entries and keeping the most recent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM user.status s
WHERE s.order_id IN ('0004','0005') AND
      s.updated_on = (SELECT MAX(s2.updated_on)
                      FROM user.status s2
                      WHERE s2.order_id = s.order_id
                     );
```

There are other ways as well in Teradata.  The `QUALIFY` clause is one of them:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM user.status s
WHERE s.order_id IN ('0004','0005') 
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.order_id ORDER BY s.updated_on DESC) = 1;
```

I would be interested in knowing which has better performance in your case.

Comment: The `QUALIFY` solution appears to work perfectly. I'll try both and update you on performance.

Comment: For 1814 user_ids, the correlated subquery had a fetch time of 00:00:00.109 - the `QUALIFY` solution had a fetch time of 00:00:00.142, so it's slightly behind

Comment: @o037 . . . Those are short times.  I wouldn't generalize to larger sets of data, but it is interesting.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a comment but I don't have the reputation to do so, but it's best practice to never use " * " in your select statements. In more complex tables/views, they'll change and if you use " * ", you're going to eventually run into problems by selecting more columns than you originally wanted.